# Entity Framework 4 column conversions - SQL Server - SQLite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, datasource, entity-framework-4, poco

I have a SQL Server database and Entity Framework Model setup with POCO objects, this is working fine. However, I have also created a Sqlite database from the SQL Server database (using a simple conversion process).

So I have created another EDMX file for the SQLite database, which I would like to use my existing POCOs generated from the SQL Server model and map them to the database. Unfortunately this maps the SQLite primary key integer columns as int64 (this seems to be the underlying integer type in SQLite), when they are simply ints in the SQL Server database.

This means when I try to map the new SQLite EDMX to my existing POCO objects (generated from the SQL Server EDMX by the POCO T4 Template), the objects cannot be mapped at runtime (and throw exceptions) because the id columns differ in type.

Does anyone know of a fix for this, for example is there a way to convert values in the entity framework edmx file? If there isn't I would consider this a fairly major limitation of the entity framework.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Hi, I had the exact same problem and we just found out what was causing it. We thought it was the SQLite provider (phx), or the EF, but we tried with Subsonic and had the same problem. Could you show some code? Something like this: `var expression = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property( paramExpr, _properties[sortcolumn] ), typeof(object ) );` was the source of all our problems.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this comment, are you saying that it can be done? I certainly couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: What are the exceptions you get? Is it `Unable to cast the type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.`?

Comment: Don't think so, I think it was something like can't map int64 to type int in the entity model itself.